# Hot to put a background color in the angular material md-tab selected

Tags: css, angularjs-material

First of all, even if i dont like to edit this, the client must be followed.

I just want to have an output like this(edited in paint):
[image]

The default is there is no background color orange, just the line.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45941592/2530536

Comment: hi @TimM, I tried that demo already, It is using angular 2. And the problem(demo)
is when i leave on the tab-clicking thing(going to the content), the active color will disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow how I found a way using

```
.md-tab.md-active{background-color: color}
```