# How to change style of Angular Material tabs?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to set the style of active tab?

I tried using this, but it doesn't work for me:

```
::ng-deep mat-tab-label-active{
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Material customize tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940965/angular-material-customize-tab)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably forgot the `.`, try `.mat-tab-label-active`.

if this doesn't work perhaps try to force it with `!important`.

not sure if you need the `::ng-deep`

Comment: oh wow, you are right, such a silly mistake, without `::ng-deep` styling on tabs doesn't work

Comment: feel free to upvote and accept the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

If you try to set any color for *angular mat components* in your own components' `scss` this will fail always. Because all the *angular mat components* colors, like their color for `warn`, `primary`, etc. are set with `!important`.

To be able to override them either use `!important`: (in your own component's `scss`)

```
.mat-tab-label-active {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

Or set the color in the global `styles.scss`:

```
.mat-tab-label-active {
    background-color: red;
    //does not require "!important"
}
```

The global styles `scss` has a higher priority than the `color !important` interior set in the *angular mat component*, therefore you don't need to add `!important`.

Answer (score 2):

We shouldn't be using ng-deep it is part of the deprecated shadow-piercing descendant combinator which will be removed from major browsers.

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

You should be able to just refer to .mat-tab-label-active .myCustomClass. However you will probably need to also ensure that view encapsulation is set to none.

Answer (score 1):

What DrNio said is probably right, but this answer should also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45941592/7653320

It tells you to set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in the Component and then you are able to style the tabs without `::ng-deep`.