# Angular 4 angular material custom mat-tab

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

how can I customize the title with the bold

```
 <mat-card-content>
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="Item1" > </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Item2" ></mat-tab>         
    </mat-tab-group>
  </mat-card-content>
```

Item1 and Item2 must be bold

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940965/angular-material-customize-tab

Answer (score 0):

You can write CSS for **mat-tab-label** class.
Please Inspect the elements and get the Idea so you can write the proper CSS.

```
.mat-tab-label{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```