# Angular Materials - difference between mat-tab and mat-btn

Tags: css, angular, components, angular-material2

I was playing a little bit with angular materials components. I wanted to know how to overwrite style of angular materials components in scss of component, not in global.scss. And I am wondering why I can overwrite main class of  example mat-btn ".mat-raised-button" with different css styles, but for example i can't overwrite main class on mat-tabs ".mat-tab , .mat-tab-header , .mat-ink-bar". I think this is simple question maybe it's about creating content in shadow dom or something but I want some PRO to answer that question :).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Material customize tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940965/angular-material-customize-tab)

Answer (score 0):

For material components like mat-tab, you can use ng-deep in css for styling

For eg:

```
mat-tab::ng-deep {
   // your styles
}
```