# How to change background color of angular material tabs

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a component using angular material 9.

There are 3 tabs in my component.

1. Completed
2. Overdue
3. Extended

I need Completed tab label background color as green, Overdue label background color as red and Extended background color as brown.

[image: These 3 are the tabs.]

[Angular Material customize tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940965/angular-material-customize-tab)

I have tried this solution but it applies single color for all tabs. My  expectation is one color per one particular tab. Please refer the below attached image.

[image: This is the expected result]

Comment: It will be helpful to answer if you create stackblitz demo and always add relevant code when you ask any question. :)

Comment: try adding "active" class when you choose a tab, so you have '.complete.active', '.overdue.active', '.extended.active', this way you can color each as you wanted

Answer (score 1):

you can use the nth of type selector to target the tab labels and set the background alternatively you can set aria-labels for individual tabs and target the label names

Example with nth of type selector

```scss
::ng-deep {
  .mat-tab-label {
    &:nth-of-type(1){
      background-color: green;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(2){
      background-color: red;
    }
    &:nth-of-type(3){
      background-color: brown;
    }
  }
}
```

Example with aria-label

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab aria-label="completed" label="Completed"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab aria-label="overdue" label="Overdue"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab aria-label="extended" label="Extended"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```scss
::ng-deep {
  .mat-tab-label {
    &[aria-label="completed"] {
      background-color: green;
    }
    &[aria-label="overdue"] {
      background-color: red;
    }
    &[aria-label="extended"] {
      background-color: brown;
    }
  }
}
```